# Django JsonResponse display in template using JavaScript without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, json, django, google-chrome-devtools

I have Django view that is using `return JsonResponse(photoData)` to send response to template without refreshing the template web page.

I can see the response in the Chrome *Developer Tools - Network - Response* panel. It appears in format: `{"photo_id": 104}`.

Does being able to see the response here mean that it is also accessible in the template using JavaScript?

Comment: If you wrote any JavaScript for it then please show it. Also, show how you are making request i.e. using Ajax or not to the view to get the response. It is very simple but before answering I want to see how you are going about this so accordingly I can post the answer that will fulfil your requirement..

Comment: Are you able to answer first part of question before jumping to second? _Does being able to see the response here mean that it is also accessible in the template using JavaScript?_

Comment: Of course, it is accessible in the template using JavaScript without page refresh if you are getting the response:`{"photo_id": 104}` in the console withou refresing the page.

Comment: No I am only saying it is appears in  Chrome Developer Tools - Network - Response panel, not the console. Perhaps this is a Chrome developer tools question and you may not have that knowledge (i just added chrome devtools tag to question). I have no idea if it is available by Javascript in template (that is my second part of my question).

Comment: If it is coming in the Network - Response panel then it should come in the console as well check it by printing via `console.log(response)` in the template where the response is directing from backend view function.

Comment: Thanks but I am still looking for definitive confirmation of exactly what I am seeing in _Chrome Developer Tools - Network - Response panel_.  Your comment is not definitive and then goes back to second part of question eg accessing it in template by using `console.log(response)`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Yes. If the *Chrome Developer Tools - Network - Response* panel shows the expected view response `{"photo_id": 104}` then that response can be obtained in template.